# Delphi Chromium Local Storage

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

I am using Delphi Chromium Embedded DCEF3. If I run my application locally I am able to store data into Local Storage and retrieve it. If I close the application and run it again, the data is gone because Delphi Chromium Embedded does not seem to retain the data between sessions. Everything works fine if I run the application in Chrome and I know that is because Delphi Chromium Embedded DCEF3 uses files to store information. Do you know how to retain local storage data between sessions?

Thank you very much

Comment: It look like I need to change the value of the cache_path variable. Does anybody knows where and how? Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following at the end of your unit:

```
initialization
  CefCache := 'e:\temp\cef';
```

`CefCache` will be used at the initialisation of the dcef in `ceflib.pas` on line 7772.

Comment: Hi, does this setting still work? Because here it did not work, I also tested CefSettings but I did not find this Unit need uses;

Comment: @MárcioRossato Looking at the [source](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi/blob/master/source/uCEFApplication.pas#L356) `UserDataPath` would be my best guess.